# Drag and Push particle in opened mesh

Tags: three.js

I am working in three.js65. I want drag each particle and push into a bucket shape geomerty like bucket filling with ball. I also achieved drag and push. But my problem is if it is pushed inside the buket it is not visible inside bucket. It is visible form outside only but ball inside the bucket only

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please reformat your question

Comment: I need to push particle in a Bucket Shape Mesh geometry. Like bucket filling with balls. I can drag and push a particle into the bucket. The problem is if i see inside the bucket the particles are not visible. But it is visible outside of bucket merge with faces of bucket